# My pipe is not working in my if statement

Tags: bash, git

I have this script to check `git status` for all of my repositories:

```
find / -type d -name .git 2>&- | 
while read gitFolder; do
    if [[ $gitFolder == *"/Temp/"* ]]; then
        continue;
    fi
    if [[ $gitFolder == *"/Trash/"* ]]; then
        continue;
    fi
    if [[ $gitFolder == *"/opt/"* ]]; then
        continue;
    fi
    parent=$(dirname $gitFolder);
    if [[ `git -C $parent status --porcelain` ]]; then
        echo "";
        echo $parent;
        git -C $parent status --porcelain
    else if [[ $(git -C $parent status | grep ahead) ]]; then
        echo "";
        echo "$parent is not pushed yet";
    fi
done
```

But it's not working.
If I remove the second `else-block` then it works.

Basically I want to know if a git repository has any changes (first if) or if it's ahead of master (second if).

How should I change that second if condition?

Comment: Please try to be more descriptive than "not working" - what is supposed to happen, and what happens instead?

Comment: Replace `else if` with `elif`. I've not checked the code for possible further errors

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Bash `if...else if...else` statement takes the following form:

```
if CONDITION1; then
  STATEMENTS1
elif CONDITION1; then
  STATEMENTS2
else
  STATEMENTS3
fi
```

The specific error in your script is the usage of the incorrect keyword `else if` instead of the correct one `elif`.

If the CONDITION1 evaluates to True, the STATEMENTS1 will be executed. If the CONDITION2 evaluates to True, the STATEMENTS2 will be executed. If none of the test commands evaluate to True, the CONDITION3 is executed.

The conditions are evaluated sequentially. Once a condition returns True, the remaining conditions are not performed, and program control moves to the end of the if statements.

You can have one or more elif clauses in the statement.

*Suggestion:* you can install `shellcheck` package to check your bash code. See https://github.com/koalaman/shellcheck for reference.

Answer (score -1):

Try replacing

```
    else if [[ $(git -C $parent status | grep ahead) ]]; then
```

with

```
    else if git -C $parent status | grep ahead; then
```

You might also want to add `-q` to grep.

This works by replacing the `[[` test with a naked command.  The last command in the pipeline (`grep`) exits with a true or false value, depending if it found anything or not.  The `-q` option tells it to only return with that value and not actually print what it found.

Note: there are other errors in your script that also need fixing.

Comment: I don't understand it. Where is the **checking** in the second line? It seems like JavaScript.

Comment: Did not work. Gives me syntax error. Near `done`.

Comment: @SaeedNeamati please don't tell us "did not work" or "syntax error". Edit your question, and show us what _exact_ errors you get. We can't just guess what you need.

Comment: @terdon, I wrote the error. `Syntax error, near done`. I managed to make it work by changing the approach though.

Comment: You will need to combine the multiple answers here to get a working solution as you have multiple errors.  Error near done is one or more missing `fi` to close your `if`s.  Or replace `else if` with `elif`

Comment: `elif` is the way to go.

Comment: I was thinking elif was a bash feature, but it looks like POSIX added it when I wasn't looking or something.  With that out of the way, there's probably not an issue with backwards compatibility, and `elif` does look like the way to go.